# deploy mongodb with helm : " command replSetGetStatus requires authentication"?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, replicaset, helm3

I created a cluster in google cloud, deployed mongodb using help:

```
helm install my-release \
    --set auth.rootPassword=password,auth.databases[0]="database",auth.usernames[0]="root",architecture=replicaset,auth.replicaSetKey="keykfjhewq",auth.enabled=true \
    bitnami/mongodb
```

All is up, but when I exec into the pods and do `rs.status()` I get:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "command replSetGetStatus requires authentication",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1653254244, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"EZ4IdSOklvKSvSmWVYU6Rr/VcaM="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("7100667090272518150")
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1653254244, 1)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This error is stating that everything is running correctly, however in order to access the replica sets you need to first authenticate (you told it to use auth in your `--set` values with `auth.enabled=true`). To authenticate you need to tell mongo to use admin privileges and log in with the username and password you set up:

```sh
use admin
db.auth(username, password)
```

This will get you authenticated and allowed to use the shell.

Comment: Hey, firstly thanks for your help - once I exec into the pod and did the command it did init the rs, but is there a way to have it done in advanced with helm? it is not the best way to log manually inside it.. ;)

Comment: you might start with looking at a script template akin to [this bitnami template](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/mongodb/templates/replicaset/scripts-configmap.yaml) where they [configure replicaset configs at startup](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/mongodb/templates/replicaset/scripts-configmap.yaml#L204)